# Can you place $15$ integers around a circle such that sum of every $4$ consecutive numbers is either $1 $ or $ 3$?

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I found this question in a Russian Olympiad book and has left me completely stupefied. Though I have done questions regarding abstract concepts like the Pigeon Hole principle, but still because I am new to such concepts I have been unable to even start thinking about the solution.

The question goes like this:

**Can you place $15$ integers around a circle such that sum of every $4$ consecutive numbers is either $1 $ or $ 3$?**

The question puts no constraints over the distinctness of the integers and has been framed exactly in the same manner.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible.  Proceed by contradiction, suppose we had such an arrangement,$\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{15}$.  Considering all $15$ possible sums of $4$ consecutive values, we say that there are $n$ that add to $3$ and $m$ that add to $1$.  Of course $$n+m=15$$

Let $\sum a_n$ be the sum of all the integers on your circle.  Clearly, each integer appears in exactly $4$ sums.  Thus $4\sum a_n$ is the sum of all the separate sums of $4$ consecutive integers.  Thus $$4\sum a_n=3n+m$$

Subtracting our first equation from this one we see that $$2n=4\sum a_n-15$$ which is impossible (as $15$ is odd).